# How to append the json results to select dropdown using php jax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have list of json results but cant get into select html tried the following code

Json ouput:
jquery loop on Json data using $.each

```
{"Eua":"Eua","Ha'apai":"Ha'apai","Niuas":"Niuas","Tongatapu":"Tongatapu","Vava'u":"Vava'u"}

 success: function(result){
                    
                    console.log(data);
                    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                    jQuery.each(data,function(key, value)
                {   //jQuery("#state").html();
                    console.log(key);
                    jQuery("#state").html('<option>'+value+'</option>');
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the instruction

```
jQuery("#state").html(...)
```

would replace the previous option with new one, so you will always get only one option, which is the last Json value.

You should use

```
jQuery("#state").append(...)
```

This instruction would append an option to the select dropdown, remaining the previous options in place.

Comment: using append will adding to the exist option how to remove alrady existing otopns from select dropdown

Comment: @GopiNathan empty it first `jQuery("#state").empty()`